# Final Semester project about semantic analysis/information retrieval

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, machine-learning, semantics, nltk

I'm moving to my final year at college Engineering Computer Science  department and i wanted to have my graduation project in a topic related to information retrieval & semantic analysis.

I've had my internship in those topics and i'm very interested to continue in them 
so if you could please give me some examples of good Real projects to do and practice in order to be good in those fields

I want something beyond simple recommendation systems in websites

my related backGround : 
i worked before on making classifiers using wikipedia data 
i have a fair knowledge working with Huge datasources like dbpedia , probase , freebase ..etc 
i know fair knowledge about , NLP , classifiers , semantics , RDF , sentiment analysis 
i have a good web development knowledge
i have a good knowledge about scrapping data from facebook blogs and other websites

Comment: This is a bit too broad.  Scan recent conference and journal papers and find a topic that interests you.  Twitter is an easy enough data source and seems to be very hype-worthy.